# Does kubectl exec bypass the container's defined entrypoint?

Tags: kubernetes

I have an entrypoint defined in my container image, and it runs before the args specified in my deployment manifest, as it should.  But when I execute a command on that container using `kubectl exec`, it seems to bypass the container entrypoint.  Is this the expected behavior?  Can I somehow force it to always use the entrypoint commands?

Comment: yes, that's expected, kubectl exec spawns a new process in the container. i don't think theres a way to redirect this to your entrypoint.

Comment: what would be the use case?

Comment: Just a convenience.  The entrypoint script installs some secrets as env vars, then executes the remaining commands in that environment.  But when I exec to it, those aren't set.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: i'd think the env vars should be set. gonna test this.

Comment: probably depends on how you set the env vars. when set in the Dockerfile or kubernetes template or by exporting they should be available.

Comment: In this case, the shell script that runs in entrypoint sets the env vars, then execs the remaining commands into the same shell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's expected. If you really want what's in the `entrypoint.sh` you can do something like this:

```
kubectl exec -it <pod-name> -c <container-name> -- /path/to/entrypoint.sh
```

Hope it helps!